# Tables in two column beamer presentation

Tags: tables, beamer, presentations

Is there a possibility put the Table described in the image to in just one left column in beamer presentation (maybe by changing the text size for the concerned frame).
Image:
[image]

My result:
[image]

Code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Warsaw}

}
\useoutertheme{tree}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}

  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\drv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Short title]{Full Title of the Talk}
\author{John Smith} 
\institute[UCLA] 
{
University of California \\ 
\medskip
\textit{john@smith.com} 
}
\date{\today} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{First Section} 

\subsection{Subsection Example} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Multiple Columns}
\begin{columns}[c] % The "c" option specifies centered vertical alignment while the "t" option is used for top vertical alignment

\column{.45\textwidth} % Left column and width
\textbf{Heading}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Illustrative calculation for numerical example 2 (Algorithm \ref{ALG_3}).}
\label{tab:Example 2.2}
\centering
\footnotesize%scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
\normalfont Steps & Numerical computation\\
\midrule
\textbf{Input}  &   Given\\
  & $ U|_{\theta=0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0.2298 & 0.5000 & 0.7702 & 0.1250 \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
  & $U'_{\theta}|_{\theta =0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 & 0.8415 & 1 & -0.8415 & 0.7500  \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
  & $ v = \begin{bmatrix} -2.7063 & 1.0000 & 0.2298 & 0.5000 & 0.7702 & 0.1250 \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
  & $ u = \begin{bmatrix} -0.8905 & 0.3290 & 0.0756 & 0.1645 & 0.2534 & 0.0411 \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
    \midrule
Step 1: & Compute $\|U\|'_{\theta} = 2.4257$\\ 
Step 5: & Calculate $v'_{\theta} =$ \\
   & $\begin {bmatrix} 
    -4.4257 & 2.0000 & 0.8415 & 1.0000 & -0.8415 & 0.7500 
     \end{bmatrix}^T$\\ 
Step 7: & Compute $\|v'_{\theta}\| = 4.6451$\\  
Step 8: & Calculate $u'_{\theta} = $ \\
   & $\begin {bmatrix} 
    -0.0952 & 0.1552 & 0.1613 & 0.0776 & -0.6642 & 0.1839 
     \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
Step 9: & Find $ Q'_{\theta} = $\\
   &   $\begin{bmatrix*}[r] 
    -0.3390 &  0.3390 &  0.3017 &  0.1695 & -1.1348 &  0.3354\\ 
     0.3390 &  0.2042 & -0.1296 & -0.1021 &  0.3585 & -0.1338\\ 
     0.3017 & -0.1296 & -0.0488 & -0.0648 &  0.0178 & -0.0411\\
     0.1695 & -0.1021 & -0.0648 & -0.0511 &  0.1792 & -0.0669\\ 
    -1.1348 &  0.3585 &  0.0187 &  0.1792 &  0.6733 & -0.0386\\ 
     0.3354 & -0.1338 & -0.0411 & -0.0669 & -0.0386 & -0.0303
        \end{bmatrix*}$\\
Step 10: & Extract $Q'_{\theta} = Q'_{\theta}(1,1:6)= $\\ 
  &$\begin{bmatrix} -0.3390 & 0.3390 & 0.3017 & 0.1695 & -1.1348 & 0.3354 \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
Step 11: & $R'_{\theta} = \begin{bmatrix} 2.4257 \end{bmatrix}$ \\
\midrule
\textbf{Output} & $R'|_{\theta = 0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} 2.4257 \end{bmatrix}$\\
\midrule
\textbf{Test} & Accuracy of the computations:\\
& $\|(U^TU)'_{\theta}|_{\theta=0.5} - (R^TR)'_{\theta}|_{\theta=0.5}\|=1.7764\cdot10^{-15}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
%Frame----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\Huge{\centerline{The End}}
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably nobody of your audience will be able to read it, but if you use `\tiny` as font size and move the caption in the other column, the table can be squeezed into your frame:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Warsaw}

}
\useoutertheme{tree}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{enumerate}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\drv}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Multiple Columns}
\begin{columns} 
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth} % Left column and width
\tiny%scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
\normalfont Steps & Numerical computation\\
\midrule
\textbf{Input}  &   Given\\
  & $ U|_{\theta=0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0.2298 & 0.5000 & 0.7702 & 0.1250 \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
  & $U'_{\theta}|_{\theta =0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 2 & 0.8415 & 1 & -0.8415 & 0.7500  \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
  & $ v = \begin{bmatrix} -2.7063 & 1.0000 & 0.2298 & 0.5000 & 0.7702 & 0.1250 \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
  & $ u = \begin{bmatrix} -0.8905 & 0.3290 & 0.0756 & 0.1645 & 0.2534 & 0.0411 \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
    \midrule
Step 1: & Compute $\|U\|'_{\theta} = 2.4257$\\ 
Step 5: & Calculate $v'_{\theta} =$ \\
   & $\begin {bmatrix} 
    -4.4257 & 2.0000 & 0.8415 & 1.0000 & -0.8415 & 0.7500 
     \end{bmatrix}^T$\\ 
Step 7: & Compute $\|v'_{\theta}\| = 4.6451$\\  
Step 8: & Calculate $u'_{\theta} = $ \\
   & $\begin {bmatrix} 
    -0.0952 & 0.1552 & 0.1613 & 0.0776 & -0.6642 & 0.1839 
     \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
Step 9: & Find $ Q'_{\theta} = $\\
   &   $\begin{bmatrix*}[r] 
    -0.3390 &  0.3390 &  0.3017 &  0.1695 & -1.1348 &  0.3354\\ 
     0.3390 &  0.2042 & -0.1296 & -0.1021 &  0.3585 & -0.1338\\ 
     0.3017 & -0.1296 & -0.0488 & -0.0648 &  0.0178 & -0.0411\\
     0.1695 & -0.1021 & -0.0648 & -0.0511 &  0.1792 & -0.0669\\ 
    -1.1348 &  0.3585 &  0.0187 &  0.1792 &  0.6733 & -0.0386\\ 
     0.3354 & -0.1338 & -0.0411 & -0.0669 & -0.0386 & -0.0303
        \end{bmatrix*}$\\
Step 10: & Extract $Q'_{\theta} = Q'_{\theta}(1,1:6)= $\\ 
  &$\begin{bmatrix} -0.3390 & 0.3390 & 0.3017 & 0.1695 & -1.1348 & 0.3354 \end{bmatrix}^T$\\
Step 11: & $R'_{\theta} = \begin{bmatrix} 2.4257 \end{bmatrix}$ \\
\midrule
\textbf{Output} & $R'|_{\theta = 0.5} = \begin{bmatrix} 2.4257 \end{bmatrix}$\\
\midrule
\textbf{Test} & Accuracy of the computations:\\
& $\|(U^TU)'_{\theta}|_{\theta=0.5} - (R^TR)'_{\theta}|_{\theta=0.5}\|=1.7764\cdot10^{-15}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.35\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Illustrative calculation for numerical example 2 (Algorithm \ref{ALG_3}).}
\label{tab:Example 2.2}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Some other comments:

- You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{enumerate}` with beamer
- frames are centred by default, so `[c]` is unnecessary
- floating specifier such as `[H]` don't make sense in a documentclass without floats.

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues in your code:

1. You're not building any second column at all.

   - In this case Beamer simply *adjusts* the position of the only column you're building.
2. The width of your tabular is way too large to fit neatly inside one column of just 45% of the width of your document.
3. I'd rather build the `columns` structure with this command:

   ```
   \begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
   ```

   the `onlytextwidth` is specially useful when working with Beamer.

Comment: First problem solved, about the second is there a way to change the text size?